# Can I make a Ubuntu bootable USB on a Mac?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, mac

So basically I want to install ubuntu on a usb from my mac (on a laptop which usually runs windows), because I deleted the partition of ubuntu and the grub switcher was gone at the same time too (so I couldn't boot in both the operating systems) But when I tried to boot up from the usb (made on a mac) it said:
 `non-system disk
       press any key to reboot...` and then it just opens the grub rescue.
When I try stuff in the grub rescue the only thing it returns is unknown filesystem or
Is this error caused by the type of ubuntu I installed on the usb? Here are some specs of both my mac and my pc.
They both are 64-bit and an i5, it is an kingston data traveller g3 media usb. I made the bootable USB with the linux live USB loader for mac. 
I hope some of you know what to do...
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Seems to me a problem with using software on a MAC and not with Ubuntu ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Wine(Download:https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/macosx/i686/winehq-staging-1.9.14.pkg) with Rufus(https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale=en_US).

I hope I could help you.